# Modify each element depending on previous elements

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm, coding-style

I'm looking to see if there's a more idiomatic/concise/neat solution than what I have for this.

I have a list of boxes with heights and I want to stack them; that is, add to each box the distance to its center from the origin. See below:

```
  |->|-----| -|   |
h1|  |  .  |<-|y1 |
  |->|_____|      |
  |->|-----|      |
  |  |     |      |
h2|  |  .  |<-----|y2
  |  |     |
  |->|_____|
```

My solution is this:

```
L = {
   {h -> 1},
   {h -> 2}
  };
(* measure distances *)
Y = y -> # & /@ ((h/2 /. L) + Most@Accumulate[h /. {{h -> 0}}~Join~L]);
(* append distances to elements *)
L = MapThread[Append[#1, #2] &, {L, Y}]

Out= {
      {h -> 1, y -> 1/2}, 
      {h -> 2, y -> 2}}
```

So I'm getting a list of the edges and a list of the local centers and adding those.

Is there a different/better way to modify each element in a list, depending on previous elements? I would especially appreciate a shorthand for `MapThread[Append[...`

**Solution**

Combining the first two responses gives us

```
L = {{h -> 1}, {h -> 2}};
Y = Thread[y -> Accumulate[h /. L] - (h/2 /. L)]
(* one of: *)
L = {L, Y}\[Transpose] // Map@Flatten
L = Flatten/@Transpose@{L,Y}
L = Flatten/@Thread@{L,Y}
```

where `\[Transpose]` is entered with `:tr:`, which I like a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
L = {{h -> 1}, {h -> 2}};

Y = Thread[y -> Flatten[Accumulate[Values@L ] - Values@L/2]];

Join[L, List /@ Y, 2]
```

> ```
>  {{h -> 1, y -> 1/2}, {h -> 2, y -> 2}}
> ```

Or

```
MapThread[Append] @ {L, Y}
```

> ```
>  {{h -> 1, y -> 1/2}, {h -> 2, y -> 2}}
> ```

Or

```
Flatten /@ Thread @ {L, Y}
```

> ```
>  {{h -> 1, y -> 1/2}, {h -> 2, y -> 2}}
> ```

Comment: Much better usage of Thread! Changing the + to -, I don't know how I missed that thanks. I like the currying in your second example too.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[h, y]
a = {1, 2};
b = Accumulate[a] - a/2;
Transpose[{Thread[h -> a], Thread[y -> b]}]
```

> {{h -> 1, y -> 1/2}, {h -> 2, y -> 2}}

Comment: I like the transpose a lot because I can use :tr:. I just have to map Flatten to finish this one off. Thanks!